# Exception when using linqkit: Unable to cast object of type TypedParameterExpression to type LambdaExpression

Tags: c#, linq, generics, exception, linqkit

first time I've not managed to find an existing answer to my problem.

Basically I have a generic expression to allow filtering active items on an IQueryable usage:

```
queryableGoesHere.ActiveAtItems(x => x.StartDate, x => x.EndDate, asAtDate, true)
```

Implementation of expression:

```
        public static Expression<Func<T, Func<T, DateTime>, Func<T, DateTime?>, DateTime?, bool?, bool>> GetActiveAtItemsExprGeneric<T>()
        where T : class
    {
        return (o, from, to, givenTime, isActive) => (!to(o).HasValue);
    }
```

I've simplified the return line to highlight the problem. It works untill I attempt to use either of the two funcs, in this case 'to(o)'.

It fails when using linqkit here:

```
return (from m in source.AsExpandable()
                where predicate.Invoke(m, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)
                select m);
```

With the exception 
"Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.TypedParameterExpression' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression'."

Now I've never passed a func and used it in an expression in this way, and my google-fu has failed to find any reference to this exception. I'm unsure if what I'm doing is even possible... Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I think the problem are the two `Func<..>` arguments. Try changing them to `Expression<Func<...>>` and use `Invoke` inside, e.g. `to.Invoke(o)`

Comment: Thanks Ivan. I changed the signature to `Expression<Func<T, DateTime>>, Expression<Func<T, DateTime?>>` and the call now uses `(!to.Invoke(o).HasValue);`. However still receiving the same error :(

Comment: Hmm, too bad:( Can't you change `GetActiveAtItemsExprGeneric` to actually have arguments and just return `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` that you can later just `Invoke(m)`?

Comment: Yep, thanks Ivan, was following the pattern we've been using for these expressions. However you're right, doing that seems to have solved the problem :)